# Configuring Apache to forward requests to a custom (non-HTTP) process on host

Tags: apache

I'd appreciate advise in configuring Apache (2.4.4) to forward traffic (i.e. the entries to a web form) to an external process running on the same host as Apache, but listening on a port say 4321.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an answer on the Apache forum. Thought I'd post it here for posterity's sake

> I don't think this is an apache/httpd issue, but rather a programing
>   one. The form, when submitted, will go to a script that will process
>   the values on the form (hidden as well as user entered) and can do
>   whatever is necessary to send these data on in whatever manner is
>   needed. You may need to pick the programming language that back-ends
>   the form with a little care to make certain it can do what is
>   required, but the basic ones (things like perl and php) should be
>   able to handle this. You just need someone to do the necessary
>   programming.